# Exibir uma confirmação ao tentar fechar um JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Estou criando um programa utilizando `JInternalFrame`, mas gostaria de solicitar uma confirmação caso o usuário clique no botão fechar "Closable".

Para isso, estou tentando sobrescrever os métodos `internalFrameClosed` e  `internalFrameClosing`, mas ainda não sei bem como prosseguir, tentei colocar o `setClosable(false)` mas não adiantou.

Comment: Olá Juliano, verifique se a solução definida para essa pergunta te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633164/how-to-ask-are-you-sure-before-close-jinternalframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um `InternalFrameListener` ao frame interno e sobrescrever o método [`internalFrameClosing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/event/InternalFrameListener.html#internalFrameClosing-javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent-), pois ele é que é chamado quando se tenta fechar o `JInternalFrame`.

Mas como esse tipo de janela interna possui, por padrão, o comportamento de ficar oculta ao fechá-la, não adianta apenas implementar algo nesse método, é preciso dizer a janela para não fazer nada quando for fechada, deixando assim todo o controle no método sobrescrito. Para isso, basta definir o padrão de fechamento:

```
seuFrameInterno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

E depois adicionar o listener:

```
seuFrameInterno.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {

        int op = JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(getInstance(), "Quer mesmo fechar essa janela?", "Fechar Janela",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (op == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Repare que estou usando `showInternalConfirmDialog()` pois já que se trata de frames internos, não tem sentido exibir uma janela do `JOptionPane` a nivel da tela principal, e sim, apenas dentro do `JDesktopPane`. E é obrigatório passar a instancia do frame interno como primeiro parâmetro. Você pode fazer isso criando um método `getInstance()` que retorne a propria instância da classe, como eu fiz:

```
private Component getInstance() {
    return this;
}
```

Veja em funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado

Comment: @JulianoSilveira disponha :)

Comment: Downvoter, porque você não mostra que tem um pouco de dignidade e aponte onde está o erro na resposta ou o que pode ser melhorado? Mostre que você realmente entende do assunto, e negativou com criterio do post, e não por implicancia comigo ;)